# Как кастомизировать js-файл компонента ядра Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

В компоненте ядра /bitrix/components/bitrix/tasks.iframe.popup нужно поправить файл script.js.

На просторах нашлась такая статья - https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=5258, но найти настройки редактируемого компонента не удалось.

Подскажите, как решить проблему?

Comment: просто перенесите все в папку `/local/components/bitrix/tasks.iframe.popup` и там себе просто редактируйте этот файл

Comment: @Oleksandr Спасибо!